# High-Resolution Operina Scans

Tags: typography, book, history

I'm not sure if this is the right forum but there doesn't seem to be a dedicated typography forum.

I'm looking for high-resolution scans from pages of Arrighi's *La Operina*, which is a classic manual for calligraphy and for the 'chancery italic' approach to pre-printing-press typography. I'm aware of an [on line resource](http://www.operina.com/) of "the" work, but the resolution is too low.

The work doesn't have to be authentic and I'll consider examples of modern  interpretations. I have a copy of *Three Classics of Italian Calligraphy* but it doesn't show enough detail.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest asking a question like this over at typophile.org

Comment: @DA01 Thanks. I tried visiting that site but it didn't seem to have any typography-related content. Furthermore, the site was offering its own domain for sale. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Sorry! It's .com. Typophile.com it's a place with a lot of type 'scholars' in that they tend to know quite a bit of the historical aspects of the industry. (Click the FORUMS section)

Comment: @DA01 Thanks. Looks like the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is a copy on Archive.org: http://archive.org/details/laoperinadiludou00arri which seems to be higher resolution.

If that doesn't suit, my suggestion would be to buy http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ihof/p22-operina/gallery.html and use it to re-set the text you need --- if you just want the cleaned-up appearance you could use Adobe Poetica.

John Howard Benson made a lovely translation, which I highly recommend. While the English pages are still copyrighted, the Italian are public domain.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the book! I'm not really interested in the font (copy).